# How to get the current project path from eclipse using java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project named SampleProj in eclipse.

The project structure is mentioned as below :

```
SampleProj
   |  
    -- META-INF
            |
             -- dbdetails.properties
```

Currently,I'm reading the file like this :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("C://Workspace//SampleProj/META-INF//dbdetails.properties");
```

But this path is local to my system rit. So, I want to make this path generic.

So, I'm trying to keep the path like this :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("SampleProj/META-INF//dbdetails.properties");
```

But,I'm getting file not found exception.

How can I read this file from Project. Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Comment: You can set working dir when running your app. If you set it to `C://Workspace` your code will work.

Comment: @ma3stro it will only work if `META-INF` is included into project as resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to **Run**/**Run Configurations...**
- Select the **Launch Configuration** that you want to use
- Select the tab **Arguments**
- In the **Working directory** section, click **Other**
- Put **C:\Workspace** in the text field
- Click **Apply**

Then `SampleProj/META-INF/dbdetails.properties` should work as path since a relative path is relative to the user working directory corresponding to the [System property `user.dir`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: did it help somehow?

Comment: Yeah, it helped me. Thanks a a lot Nicolas

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve using :

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Then you can do it like this :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(workingDir +"//SampleProj//META-INF//dbdetails.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

As fas as your development is concerned you can do it like below but once you deploy the project its better to add file in classpath

```
String currentDirectory=System.getProperty("user.dir");


FileReader reader = new FileReader(currentDirectory+"/SampleProj/META-INF//dbdetails.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your using spring web-mvc project use this samplecode:

```
String path=session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/ui_resources/images/logo.png");
```